# HTML/CSS block and relative positioning

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to position 4 blocks two on top and two at the bottom using the relative positioning and div blocks. However, the second block for some reasons are not showing. Need HELP!~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{text-align:center;}
span{display:block}
#block1{    
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    position: relative;
    left:0; top:0;
    border: 1px solid black;
#block2{    
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right:0; top:0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    </style>
</head>

<body>



<div id="block1"> <span> left:0;top:0; </span></div>
<div id="block2"><span> right:0;top:0;</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can create a container as a relative container and 4 absolute elements inside it and decide on the positions with top left right bottom locations.

Answer (score 1):

[There was a typo check the answer](http://jsfiddle.net/5aKrQ/1/)

### css

```
    div{text-align:center;}
    span{display:block}
    #block1{    
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding:0px;
        position: relative;
        left:0; top:0;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #block2{    
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        right:0; top:0;
    border: 1px solid black;

     }
    #block3{    
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    position: relative;
    left:0; top:0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
#block4{    
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right:0; top:0;
border: 1px solid black;

float:left;
 }
```

### HTML

```
<div id="block1"> <span> left:0;top:0; </span></div>
<div id="block2"><span> right:0;top:0;</span></div>
<div id="block3"> <span> left:0;top:0; </span></div>
<div id="block4"><span> right:0;top:0;</span></div>
```

### o/p

[image: Output]